# SKSpriteNode : Handling Collision during SKAction

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I'm making a little game, and I'm now stuck with the following problem.

I'm running an action (followPath type) on a particular node :

```
let followTrack: SKAction = SKAction.followPath(ballPath!.CGPath, duration: ACTION_SPEED)
movingBall.runAction(followTrack)
```

But during the animation, if the node collide with another one (like a wall for exemple), the animation stops and there is no collision animation.

I tried some things like :

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

    firstBody.node?.removeAllActions()
    secondBody.node?.removeAllActions()
}
```

But there is no collision either (I guess that's because velocity is (0,0))

Is there anyway to handle this case ? (I don't especially need a swift answer, an objective-C or generic answer would be great too !)

Comment: you can't mix move actions with physics - either move the node with physics or with actions, you can't have both. Movement by actions will ignore physics properties (ie collisions, forces) while physics tries to compensate for external movement (moving node outside collision). In the end you get strange behavior. You can only mix move action on a physics node if you merely use physics to determine contact (collision detection) but don't allow collision feedback from the physics engine.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Yes, I'm using `SKAction` because I did not find another good way to make a node follow a particular path. So I was hoping a cool trick to handle this problem :)

Comment: What you have posted is contact handling. Contacts are just notifications of two physicsBodies intersecting each other. A collision on the other hand is where two volume-based physicsBodies interact with each other based on physics simulation.

Comment: In order to use followPath, you will need to move away from physics and create your own mechanisms for showing collision animations.

Comment: @ZeMoon In fact, using custom mechanic means changing velocity vector on contact. But during a `followPath` there is no velocity on the node, so even in this case I don't see how to handle the collision.