# Physics body as an SKTexture does not rotate

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite, xcode7, physics

I am making a game where the main character rotates, however, I want to use an SKTexture to set custom boundaries to the character sprite node. However, when I do this, my character does not rotate. When I use a regular circleOfRadius (because my sprite is round, but no perfectly round) it rotates, but is not accurate on collisions. Here is my code:

```
    var mainSpriteTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Main")
    mainSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: mainSpriteTexture)
    mainSprite.setScale(0.2)
    mainSprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: 100)


    mainSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: mainSpriteTexture, size: mainSprite.size)
    mainSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.player
    mainSprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.platform | PhysicsCatagory.ground
    mainSprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.platform | PhysicsCatagory.ground | PhysicsCatagory.score
    mainSprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    mainSprite.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    mainSprite.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    self.addChild(mainSprite)


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    updateSpritePosition()
    if gameStarted == true {
        if died == false {
            mainSprite.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(direction, (mainSprite.physicsBody?.velocity.dy)!)
        }
        else if died == true {
            mainSprite.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, (mainSprite.physicsBody?.velocity.dy)!)
        }
    }
```

Here is the shape I am using: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8VfW.jpg

Comment: Can you add a shape you use, as well as the code responsible for rotating? Or the sprite is rotated as a result of interaction with other objects ? This way, nobody can't say for sure what is going on because your problem can't be re-created...

Comment: I added some more code. The sprite is always suppose to be rotating whenever the game starts.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are interested in realistic physics simulation, you should move objects by forces or impulses (or directly by changing velocity vector). If you manually change node's position through position property, or you use SKAction, you may experience weird results, because you are pulling a sprite out of a physics simulation. Physics and manual node movement (using SKAction for example) is safe only if you are interested in just contact detection. If you want collisions, you should let the physics engine to move your objects.

Comment: Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26909774/3402095) about all this (read comments posted by LearnCocos2d).

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure how you rotate your sprite, or move it, but if I give it a certain default rotation and drop it on the surface, it rotates for me as it should (I used a picture you have provided). This way, it will not land perfectly on the ground (`zRotation 0.0`).

Try to use this:

```
mainSprite.zRotation = 0.1 //note that these are radians
```

and drop it on a flat surface.

Same thing you could probably achieve by applying a small force or impulse which should affect sprite's `zRotation` property... What you are going to use, depends on how you move your node actually - using physics, or by changing its position property directly (see my comment about mixing physics & manual node movement for important details).